# PHP - Form content into a variable

Tags: php

I would like to get the contents of an input from a form using:

```
$_POST['poll-description'];
```

But I would like to put the result of this into a new variable `$description`.

Can I set a `$` variable to have the content of another `$` variable?

Something like this?
`$description = $_POST['poll-description'];`

Comment: $description = $_POST['poll-description']; - yes this is how it works

Comment: That's not _`PHP statement within a statement`_. You were assigning value to the another varibale

Comment: did you mean to use your variable as double $ variable like $$a

Comment: in your example you are assigning the `value` of the `array element` with `key`  poll-description of the `array` $_POST, which is a special array that contains all `post data` to a (new) `variable` called $description

Comment: @Thomas Ok. So would what I have written above return the value of `$_POST['poll-description'];` when I use `$description` What I'm asking is, is it correct?

Comment: @dwinnbrown exactly: `$_POST['poll-description'];` is not a function but an array element.

Answer (score 1):

That is how you declare / set a new variable to another variables value. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Answer (score 1):

The `$` is not a statement, it is a character that always prefixes variables. What you are effectively doing is the same as:

In **Javascript**:

```
var description = post['poll-description'];
```

In **Python**:

```
description = post['poll-description']
```

In **C#**:

```
var description = post["poll-description"];
```

Comment: Ok so would the above work? I am trying to get the content of an input form and translate it into a variable.

Comment: @dwinnbrown it would